# Send Firebase Cloud Message to all users using Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am very new to JS but I want to use cloud functions to send a Firebase Cloud Message to my app upon firestore field change.
I implemented code to recive FCM, and it works fine when i send FCM from console, but i cannot work it out with cloud functions.
Here is a piece of code from my index.js (basicly copied and pasted from internet)

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.updateStatus = functions.firestore.document('/buttonPatio/test').onUpdate(event => {
  var newValue = event.data.val();
  var message;
  if (newValue.redlight !== null) {
    message = "Status : " + newValue.redLight ;
  } 

  pushMessage(message);
  console.log("Udpated tableStatus :", JSON.stringify(newValue));
  return true;
});
function pushMessage(message) {
  var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: message,
    }
  };

  admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    return true;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    return true;
  });
}
```

Comment: when i change field in firestore, cloud message gets initiated but i get an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined at exports.updateStatus.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate.event (/user_code/index.js:37:28) at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23) at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20) at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:758:24 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)